# Using another class in java to input an option.

Tags: java, methods, parameters

Please help me with this: 
 I want to create a Library System java program in which in the main class, I will let the user enter a choice.

======= LIBRARY SYSTEM =======

1. BORROW A BOOK

2. RETURN A BOOK

3. BROWSE CATEGORIES

4. EXIT

==============================

ENTER YOUR CHOICE HERE :

then I will create a sub class for each choices above.

For example, inside my class for the choice number 1, I have the same options from the main class.

========= LIBRARY SYSTEM ========

 1. ENTER BOOK CODE

 2. BACK TO MAIN MENU

=================================

ENTER YOUR CHOICE HERE:

I want my subclass to go back to the main class when the user enters choice number 2.

sorry newbie here. Thank you!

Comment: Creating a new class for each of these seems like bad design. I'd create a new method for each. That would make what you're trying to do much easier as well

Comment: You only create a subclass for things that represent "same thing but different" objects. For example, Animal and Dog, Library and Medical Library etc. So it's not a good fit here.

Comment: @RealSkeptic I don't think the OP wants to _extend_ the main class. He/she just wants to create another class.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say that your main class is called `MainClass` and the other class is called `BorrowBook`. In `BorrowBook`, create a method that returns an `int`:

```
public static int promptUser () {
    //you can print some lines here
    //get the user input
    int input = //however you want to get the input
    return input;
}
```

Now in your main class, check if the user enters 2 using the `promptUser` method:

```
int response = BorrowBook.promptUser ();
if (response == 2) {
    //call some method to display the main menu
} else if (response == 1) {
    //call some method in the BorrowBook do whatever when the user enters 1
}
```

See? The idea is that you need to create different methods for different stuff. `displayMainMenu`, `promptUser`, `promptBookCode` etc. Don't just put all the stuff in the main method. This decreases maintainability and the level of abstraction.

Comment: I get your point. This really helps but
How to switch back to the main menu? Do I need to create a Main Menu object?

Comment: You make another method to display the main menu in your `MainClass` @nyelnyelnyel